MUI DateTimePicker component styling
I'm working on a project using Material UI (MUI) and specifically the DateTimePicker component from the @mui/x-date-pickers package. I'd like to change the colors of the AM/PM buttons.
MUI often abstracts styling details and that you have to target specific classnames through the sx props, and while I've checked the documentation, I haven't found a clear way to target these buttons for color customization.
Has anyone encountered this before and found a solution to style the AM/PM buttons in MUI's DateTimePicker? Any guidance or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!
Here is the image of the component I want to style, I have also marked the specific buttons I want to target

    .MuiDateTimePickerToolbar-ampmSelection .MuiButton-text span{color: red !important;}


.MuiDateTimePickerToolbar-ampmSelection is the class you can target to style AM/PM section.
.MuiDateTimePickerToolbar-ampmSelection .MuiButton-text .Mui-selected { color: red !important;}

This one will target just the current selected between Am and PM.
https://mui.com/x/api/date-pickers/date-time-picker-toolbar/#classes
Hope this helps.
Also given that you are new here as a fellow newbie to StackOverflow I would suggest you create a sandbox or post minimum reproducible code whenever possible. Would allow others to see and debug your issue.

This helps alot, thankyou so much, can you please guide me on how to change the color of only the selected AM PM value ? and yes thankyou for the advice I'll be surely keeping this in mind next time I ask a question

.MuiDateTimePickerToolbar-ampmSelection .MuiButton-text .Mui-selected {
color: red !important;
}
.Mui-selected - this class gets added to the selected AM/PM span, this can be used to target only selected item
Will update the answer with it.

I have not used this package, but you can use "multi date picker", it is a powerful tool and has the ability to customize.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
